# Firebase permission denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Here i am calling this function with phone number after he complete his verification an this function is adding his number using custom claim to satisfy this filebase database security rule

```js
{
"rules": {
   "Users": {
      //".read": true,
      //".write": "auth.token.phone == newData.val()",
      //".read": "auth.uid != null",
      //".write": "newData.child('Personal Details').child('phone').val() === auth.token.phone"
      "$userNumber": {
        "Personal Details": {
          ".read": "auth.uid != null",
          ".write": "auth.token.phone == $userNumber"
        },
        "Notifications": {
        ".read": "auth.token.phone === $userNumber",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null"
      },
  }
```

**Refreshing token after this function call**

```java
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getIdToken(true).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
            Log.d("firebaseFunctionCall", "onComplete: token refreshed");
            checkUser();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            loadingBar.dismiss();
            Log.d("firebaseFunctionCall", "onFailure: failed to refresh error: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

here i am doing when a user is verified his number then his phone number is also added to the database

But i am getting `Database Permission denied` error.

`userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");`

If any further details need please ask me . but please help me with this problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the client query that's not working the way you expect.

Comment: I have edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is attempting to get the entire contents of the Users node, but your security rules don't allow that.  The rules [will not filter out the nodes that the user may not access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) (please read and understand that link).  You will need to fetch only the part of the database that the user has been granted access by the rules.  This means your rules allow access to only "Users/number/Personal Details" and "Users/number/Notifications", and nothing else.

Comment: Doug Stevenson now i think that i figure out what was i missed , just tell me if i am wrong ... In my case i had no `read` `write` for `"Users"` but has for it's child like `"Personal Details"` and `"Notifications"` etc.  so when i try to write new user in `"User"` node then database give me `Permission denied ` error ... am i write? and i update my question now it's work fine ... am i doing right?

Comment: Try adding read and write access to $userNumber, not its children.

Comment: Ok ... i will try