# Firebase - Why is the claim not added to the user attributes?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm adding the claim to a user's profile that he or she paid for something, though, after the payment this attribute isn't visible. I'm running the functions on an emulator on a local host.

This is the code I'm using:

If the paypal function has been handled succesfully through paypalHandleOrder, then the function addPaidClaim is invoked.

```
  onApprove: (data, actions) => {
    paypalHandleOrder({ orderId: data.orderID }).then( 
      addPaidClaim(currentUser).then(
        alert("THANKS FOR ORDERING!"),
        // currentUser.getIdTokenResult().then(idTokenResult => {
        //   console.log(idTokenResult.claims)
        // })
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        return err;
      })
    );}
```

addPaidClaim is a firebase cloud function, which goes as follows:

```
  exports.addPaidClaim = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    // get user and add custom claim (paid)
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(data.uid, {
      paid: true,
    }).then(() => {
      return {
        message: `Success! ${data.email} has paid the course`,
      };
    }).catch((err) => {
      return err;
    });
  });
```

I've refreshed the page and checked the user attributes afterwards through console.log on the user to see if the attribute had been added, but this is not the case. I can't find attribute paid inside the idTokenResult object. What should I do? I also find it hard to make sense of what's happening inside the function addPaidClaim. It's not returning an error when I look at the logs on my firebase console, and not much information is given, besides that the function has been invoked.

Comment: The claims won't propagate immediately. You would have to refresh the token. Check this answer for detailed answer: [Firebase custom claims don't propagate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52729144/13130697)

Comment: Also, it is not safe to add custom claim by calling a function from client side. Any user can call the function without even completing the payment and it doesn't seem you have any validation in Cloud function. Consider using [Paypal Webhooks](https://www.paypal.com/in/webapps/mpp/merchant) instead.

Comment: I refreshed the page multiple times, but I still couldn't find the claim..

Comment: You need to refresh the _token_. `.getIdToken(true)` <- pass `true` to force refresh the token.

Comment: Wat would you recommend me to do then in order to do this safely? The functions are executed in the cloud

Comment: Use webhooks as mentioned in previous comment. Let paypal trigger the function for you containing payment information.

Comment: But paypalHandleOrder({ orderId: data.orderID }) is a paypal function though

Comment: But `addPaidClaim()` is custom function. You don't necessarily have to go through Paypal directly. The Cloud function can be called without Paypal being a part of your app.

Comment: Also, I did what you told me to do, pass true to force refresh the token, and I get a promise object as output. The promiseState is fulfilled, but I still don't see the attribute paid inside claims. What could be going wrong, and how could I debug this firebase cloud function?

Comment: `return user.getIdToken(true).then((token) => console.log(token))`... try this way

Comment: And yes, it's not necessary, perhaps I can split these things. But I want this claim to be added when the customer has made a succesful payment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236808/discussion-between-y-ben-and-dharmaraj).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I know this question is pretty old. But I found a way just yesterday after 3 days searching over the solution. After we set up a new claim for a new user using, we need to refresh the client's `getIdTokenResult(true)` in the app. These are the ways I did it in `Flutter Dart` until a new user with updated claim managed to use it:

```js
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> signInWithGoogle() async {
   Map<String, dynamic> output = {};
   final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
   if (googleUser == null) {
        log("Firebase => Gmail account doesn't exist");
   } else {
     final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
     final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
     );
     await auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((values) async {
        await userAuth(credential).then((value) =>          
          value.addAll(output));
     });
   }
   return output;
}

Future<Map<String, dynamic> userAuth (OAuthCredential credential) async {
   Map<String, dynamic> output = {};
   await auth.currentUser!.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential);
   await auth.currentUser!.reload();
   await auth.currentUser!.getIdTokenResult().then((result) => {
      if(result.claims!.isNotEmpty){
        //check your claim here
      } else {
        //assign log here
      }
   });
   return output;
}
```