# Custom claims set in cloud functions do not show up in cloud rules of firebase storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I'm trying to set custom claims using the following:

```js
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {['hguwukrpyrwxerqr679p']: true});
```

where `hguwukrpyrwxerqr679p` is a unique ID of an object in the firestore database. This object, when it was created, has its own bucket. This bucket has the following security rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    allow read: if request.auth.token[bucket];
    allow write: if false;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work and I get a 403 error code. I don't know why and I've tried simulating the request in the rule-playground of `firebase storage`, using the user from above. The token section does not show any custom claims at all, but it should, shouldn't it?

I've been at it for quite a few hours now, trying out various methods, even setting the claims manually in a cloud function. Can someone point me in the right direction or give hints on how to debug this problem correctly? When debugging a cloud function by executing

```
console.log(Object.keys(await admin.auth().getUser(uid).customClaims));
```

it shows the correct contents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Custom Claims doesn't propagate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729144/firebase-custom-claims-doesnt-propagate)

Comment: @Dharmaraj flutter shows me the custom claim correctly but it is still rejected

Comment: The way you set the claim itself looks unusual. Did you try: `{'hguwukrpyrwxerqr679p': true}`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've tried using `{[objectId]: true}`, `{['hguwukrpyrwxerqr679p']: true}` and `{'hguwukrpyrwxerqr679p': true}` but none of those work :(

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is there a way to debug what custom claims are read in the storage security rules? Clientside (flutter), I'm getting all the custom claims that I've set. I've tried logging in and out (as some video recommended) and I've called `getIdToken` but I still get a 403. This is driving me nuts. I've followed all instructions I've found online and everything indicates that I'm doing it correctly yet I keep getting `StorageException has occurred. User does not have permission to access this object.`

Comment: The rules are passed the claims from the ID token in the client. If the showing that decoded ID token contains the claims, they are passed from the client to the server, decoded there, and sent to the security rules.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen custom claims work in security rules of storage just like how they work in firestore, don't they? Because it works fine in firestore but I can't get storage to work.

Comment: Yup, as far as I know there should be no difference. Do the claims show up in storage rules at any point?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I feel confused after my latest discovery. Apparently, applying rules for the root of a bucket only works using the `match /{somePath=**}` wildcard. I was not aware of this. From this perspective, rules are somewhat different than `Firestore`'s rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules stored in the root of a bucket are somehow ignored.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    allow read: if request.auth.token[bucket];
    allow write: if false;
  }
}
```

Instead, a wildcard should be used

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{somePath=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.token[bucket];
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this should be accepted as an answer since it's only partially relevant to the problem.